# What is the purpose of the system owned top-level windows that have the WS_CHILD style?

Tags: windows, winapi

In the [EnumWindows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumwindows) documentation, it states:

> The EnumWindows function does not enumerate child windows, with the exception of a few top-level windows owned by the system that have the WS_CHILD style.

Does anyone know what the purpose of these windows are for?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Comment: @JonathanPotter, why is it not a programming question?  It has to do with trying to understand the windowing system.

Comment: I think this is still off-topic, as it is asking about *implementation details* that are private to the OS.  Only Microsoft uses those particular windows, they are not meant for us lonely developers to interact with, or even really know about. So why should you care how they are used?  They don't affect how we use the windowing APIs.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, _implementation details_ shouldn't be visible through the public API, and if we knew more about why, it may affect how we use the API.

Comment: @Adrian except that it isn't, really.  I've been using `EnumWindows()` for years and never even noticed these "top-level windows owned by the system that have the WS_CHILD style" before.  So even if they *exist* doesn't necessarily mean you (or your code) will see/react to them.  It really depends on what your enum callback is doing.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, just because you don't know about something, doesn't mean that it couldn't be useful to know about.  If we all took that stance, we would not progress.

Comment: @Adrian then ask Microsoft about it, it is their API.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I've heard that they are also on here, and there might be others besides yourself, who might know.

Comment: @Adrian [Raymond Chen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/902497/raymond-chen) is, at least.

Comment: Sigh.  Comments were not intended to tell everybody that you don't know the answer.  Just wait for somebody that does know the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The only place you will find this (AFAIK) is the Combobox dropdown window. This is from a time before WS_EX_NOACTIVATE and it is technically illegal for you to create this type of window with `CreateWindow`. These windows do not have normal keyboard handling even when they are active.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, they all appear to have a `ComboLBox` window style.  Do you have any references to go with this answer?  Is this automatically created by a framework?  What are they for exactly and what do they have to do with `WS_EX_NOACTIVATE`?

Comment: I have no reference because this is undocumented. The combox control creates this window. If somebody was going to code this today they would use the WS_EX_NOACTIVATE style. If you try to create a window like this without WS_EX_NOACTIVATE and without the WS_CHILD hack then this dropdown would deactivate its owner window and you don't want that in a combobox dropdown.